# ApplicationUpdaterUI fails for Mac

Tags: javascript, html, macos, air, adobe

LOG:

```
Runtime Installer begin with version 3.3.0.3650 on Mac OS 10.7.4 x86
Commandline is: -updatecheck
Installed runtime (3.3.0.3650) located at /Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework
Performing pingback request
Failure during pingback request: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=falsr eventPhase=2 text="Unhandled exception Error: Error #3001" errorID=3001]
Runtime Installer end with exit code 0
```

It works fine on Windows but fails for Mac.

Digging around I found out that the error code #3001 has something to do with file/directory permission issues.

Checked /Users/internetslave/Library/Application Support/Adobe permissions seems ok. [source](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2984830#2984830).

Checked /Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework seems ok too.

Both had drwxr-xr-x.

UPDATE: permission is not an issue, successfully updated other applications on the same system.

```
var appUpdater;

function checkForUpdates() {
    appUpdater = new air.ApplicationUpdaterUI();
    appUpdater.configurationFile = new air.File("app:/update/update-config.xml");
    appUpdater.addEventListener(air.ErrorEvent.ERROR, onCheckForUpdatesError);
    appUpdater.initialize();

    setTimeout(function() { 
        appUpdater.checkNow(); 
    }, 500);
}

function onCheckForUpdatesError(event) {
    alert(event.toString());
}
```

Cant seem to post the update configuration and descriptor files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those might stumble upon the same problem.

The problem was the ApplicationUpdaterUI has not finished initializing when the method checkNow is called.

So either, change the second parameter of the setTimeout to a higher value or place this part

```
appUpdater = new air.ApplicationUpdaterUI();
appUpdater.configurationFile = new air.File("app:/update/update-config.xml");
appUpdater.addEventListener(air.ErrorEvent.ERROR, onCheckForUpdatesError);
appUpdater.initialize();
```

in page onLoad event handler and attach the checkNow method to a button onClick event

```
function checkUpdates() {
    appUpdater.checkNow();
}

<input type="button" onclick="checkUpdates()" />
```

Thanks!